# How can i use IN operator or equivalent of it in SSAS MDX query?

Tags: ssas, mdx, in-operator

I want to use IN operator like we do in SQL

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

how can i achieve this in MDX query?

```
for eg. [Customer ID] IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Here i don't want to use where clause  as same hierarchy used in where clause cannot be selected on a axis. Is there a way to use IN operator without where clause?

I have heard of Named sets can be used with IN operator in mdx query, But i want to use a static list of values to be used with IN operator.Is it possible?

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't think this is a duplicate of the referenced question because gbc specifically says that they don't want the IN functionality in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the following MDX:

```
select 
  {[Customer].[Customer ID].[1]
  ,[Customer].[Customer ID].[2]
  ,[Customer].[Customer ID].[3]
  ,[Customer].[Customer ID].[4]
  ,[Customer].[Customer ID].[5]} on 0
from YourCube;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides [Danylo Korostil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47429647) is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    [Customer].[Customer ID].MEMBERS ON 0
FROM (
    SELECT 
        {([Customer].[Customer ID].[1]),
         ([Customer].[Customer ID].[2]),
         ([Customer].[Customer ID].[3]),
         ([Customer].[Customer ID].[4]),
         ([Customer].[Customer ID].[5])} ON 0
    FROM
        [Your Cube]
)
```

Using a subquery (or nested subqueries) worked better for me than limiting the members in the SELECT clause when I was also using SUBSET or ORDER functions.